# passing a variable to another activity and calculating it's percentage

Tags: java, android

so here is my problem : i want to pass the number entered by the user to another activity and show only 30% of it . should i use DataBase ? and how ? please any help
i will appreciate it 
thank you
i have activity_main.xml

`

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Entrez Votre Max Rep en KG"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ff4564ff"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
            <TextView
                android:text="Item1"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
            <EditText
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text="Item2"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
            <EditText
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>            
        </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Soumettre"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/submit_button"/>


</LinearLayout>`
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

first get the int values from the EditText

```
    int i = 0;

    try{

        i = Integer.parseInt(YourEditTextId.getText().toString());

    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){

        System.out.println("Value at TextView is not a valid integer");

    }      

    // activity to pass values
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,YourClass.class);
    intent.putExtra("intVariableName", value); // put value to intent
    startActivity(intent); // start intent activity
```

then in the new activity get the values and do what you want

```
    // get value
    int x = getIntent().getIntExtra("intVariableName", defaultValue);
```